# difference between asp.net cache object and application object

Tags: asp.net

Apart from having an expiration time and dependency feature , what are the other important differences between the asp.net cache and application objects since both are used for state / cache management?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Application objects were used majorily during Asp time , if you are using asp.net  i think you should go for httpcache.

This is what i remembered , we used to load everything in application object when we used to write the code in asp.